# constant ... inferred to have type '()?', which may be unexpected

Tags: swift

When I am chaining a methods on the following object

```
let developerButton = UIButton(type: .system).titleLabel?.text = "developer"
```

I get the message:

> Constant 'developerButton' inferred to have type '()?', which may be
>   unexpected

I don't get it. Any help ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `developerButton` is the result of the text assignment `text = "developer"`, which returns `Void` (nothing, `()`). The assignment is conditional and that's why you are getting `Void?` (or `()?`).

Split your two assignments correctly.

```
let developerButton = UIButton(type: .system)
developerButton.titleLabel?.text = "developer"
```

Also note that you should use `setTitle` instead of setting title text directly:

```
let developerButton = UIButton(type: .system)
developerButton.setTitle("developer", for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let developerButton = UIButton(type: .system)
developerButton.titleLabel?.text = "developer"
```